# Jenkins trigger prebuild

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to execute a maven goal before executing the current job? For example I want to execute `mvn blah blah` before `mvn clean verify test`. The `mvn clean verify test` is auto trigger when the git branch has been pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your job is a Maven job, you can add a pre-build step (shell or batch) to launch your maven command (mvn bla bla bla):

[image]

Does it help?